Using gesture detectors in overlapping widgets inside stack
I'm trying to place two overlapping widgets in a Stack and wrap those widgets with different GestureDetector widgets. My goal is to receive tap events in both GestureDetectors when tapping in the overlapping area. I've tried tweaking the behavior property with different options, but none seem to work. With my current code in the overlapping area I only get tap events from the second element.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: OverlappingStack(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class OverlappingStack extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        GestureDetector(
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
          onTap: () {
            print('First element tapped');
          },
          child: Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 200,
            color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.5),
          ),
        ),
        GestureDetector(
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
          onTap: () {
            print('Second element tapped');
          },
          child: Container(
            width: 200,
            height: 100,
            color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

How can I make both GestureDetectors receive the tap events in the overlapping area?

The Flutter gesture system is designed to allow only recognise on pointer at the time. This means only one GestureDetector will receive the tap event.
However there is a workaround, where you can just use the position and then fire the events based on that:
class OverlappingStack extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return GestureDetector(
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
          onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) {
            final RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
            final Offset localOffset = box.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
    
            if (localOffset.dx <= 100 && localOffset.dy <= 200) {
              print('First element tapped');
            }
            if (localOffset.dx <= 200 && localOffset.dy <= 100) {
              print('Second element tapped');
            }
          },
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 200,
                color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.5),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 200,
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }

Sources also mentioning this issue:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/87774
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/75099
